# Ruby on Rails, why doesn't my email system work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, smtp

I am trying to send an email to a user to confirm that they have successfully registered with the site. I have followed a guide and have the following files.

development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => ENV['email'],
 :password             => ENV['password'],
 :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module ThorCinema
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true    
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'validators')
    gmail_username: 'email'
    gmail_password: 'password'
  end

end
```

users_controller:

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
  # accessible to all pages
   session[:user_id] = @user.id
   #UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
   UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
   @user.add_default_preferences
   redirect_to films_path
else
   render action: "new"
end
end
```

mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'no-reply@thorcinemas.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    # mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

mailers/application_mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

views/welcome_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Thor Cinemas, <%= @user.first_name %>!</h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to Thor Cinemas,
      your username is: <%= @user.first_name %> <%= @user.last_name %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it does not work and when I try to run `rails s` I get this output:

```
C:\Sites\Thor\Under Construction\ThorCinema\new\Lab\Newu\ThorCinema>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/ra
iltie.rb:196:in `method_missing': undefined method `gmail_username' for ThorCine
ma::Application:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Sites/Thor/Under Construction/ThorCinema/new/Lab/Newu/ThorCinema
/config/application.rb:25:in `<class:Application>'
        from C:/Sites/Thor/Under Construction/ThorCinema/new/Lab/Newu/ThorCinema
/config/application.rb:9:in `<module:ThorCinema>'
        from C:/Sites/Thor/Under Construction/ThorCinema/new/Lab/Newu/ThorCinema
/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Show us full `config/application.rb` file.

Comment: @Зелёный I have updated the question

Comment: Why gmail_username and gmail_password in application.rb ?

Comment: @JérémyButtice I followed this guide: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails and that's what it said to enter to send from gmail. What other way could I do it?

Comment: In this tutorial, he explains to add your env var in application.yml not in application.rb, application.yml is for figaro gem.

Comment: Watch this http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

Comment: Have you tried by commenting out `gmail _uername` and `gmail_password` in `application.rb` file and add `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }`.

Comment: also please try by writing up your gmail and password in your smtp configuration instead of ENV variables if everything works then try usin ENV variables.

Comment: I don't see how your first comment would work as surely the email address needs the password to send the email. And I don't really understamd your second comment

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => ENV['email'],
 :password             => ENV['password'],
 :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

with

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => 'your_email',
 :password             => 'your_password',
 :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

and restart your server.
If it works add 'your_email' and 'your_password' in env var like this (not need figaro gem).

```
edit the ~/.bashrc file
```

and add

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME="myname@gmail.com"
```

You’ll have to open a new shell or restart your terminal application to continue.

For windows:

From the Desktop, right-click the Computer icon and select Properties. 
If you don't have a Computer icon on your desktop, click the Start button, right-click the Computer option in the Start menu, and select Properties.
    Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
    In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of that tab.
    In the Environment Variables window (pictured below), highlight the Path variable in the "System variables" section and click the Edit button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you want the computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a semicolon as shown below.

```
C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32
```

For you add gmail_username (the name of your var env) in "variable" and
add value.

[image]

Note: You can edit other environment variables by highlighting the variable in the "System variables" section and clicking Edit. If you need to create a new environment variable, click New and enter the Variable name and Variable value.

Comment: Where is the `bashrc file`?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, I've followed your advice for windows and when I click edit on the system variable "path" I get the following: variable name: Path variable value: C:\Program Files\...C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64\ (I have had to shorten the variable value to fit) what are you saying that I should do?

Comment: you should not change but click on 'New' to add a Windows environment variable that will contain your gmail password.
Its values are then accessible via the rails application like this ENV['gmail_email'] ('gmail_email' must match with variable name value that you entered on windows...) and value contain your really gmail username, do you understand ?

Comment: Ok, so I add a new SYSTEM VARIABLE with the name gmail_email and the value being the email address, and the same for password? So two different variables?

Comment: One variable for email, and one different variable for password.

Comment: Yes close all and restart your server rails then test.

Comment: I didn't get an error, just didn't get an email. Everything worked except the email